# Info Path form - validation to only allow selected choices from a dropdown

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, infopath, validation

Summary - I have a field in a SharePoint (2010) list set to be selected from a drop-down, choices hard coded:

[image]

The field is entered using an InfoPath designed form.

There's a request to reorganize the list by category and add header-like category entries in the list to ease lookup - Programmer, Security, etc.

Changing the order of the list is easy, as is adding in category entries.  But I've no idea if there's a way to tell the system not to allow selection of certain options in the dropdown.

I expect I could add a test in the workflow for the table, but I don't know how to send the record back to the edit form if the test fails. Seems that handling it in the form is better.

Thoughts?